# Unable to open java project in sts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipse, sts

Im using spring tool suite 4, my gradle application uses java 8 and gradle 7.2 previously. Now I have upgraded java version as java 17 and gradle 8.0.2. I was unable to open java classes in sts, its throwing the following exception while opening java classes in sts editor.

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @16da476c
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.overrideLoadResult(ModuleClassLoader.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.endParse(Parser.java:10861)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.CommentRecorderParser.endParse(CommentRecorderParser.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.endParse(SourceElementParser.java:809)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12044)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12268)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:12225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.SourceElementParser.parseCompilationUnit(SourceElementParser.java:1034)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.buildStructure(CompilationUnit.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:312)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.getSourceRange(CompilationUnit.java:951)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.selectionactions.GoToNextPreviousMemberAction.update(GoToNextPreviousMemberAction.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.selectionactions.GoToNextPreviousMemberAction.<init>(GoToNextPreviousMemberAction.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.selectionactions.GoToNextPreviousMemberAction.newGoToNextMemberAction(GoToNextPreviousMemberAction.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.createActions(JavaEditor.java:2744)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.createActions(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractTextEditor.java:3483)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusTextEditor.createPartControl(StatusTextEditor.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.createPartControl(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.createPartControl(JavaEditor.java:3123)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor.createPartControl(CompilationUnitEditor.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:361)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:998)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:963)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:662)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1293)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.lambda$0(LazyStackRenderer.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.lambda$0(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4622)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElementGen(ElementContainerImpl.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3205)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.lambda$9(WorkbenchPage.java:3110)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3108)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3078)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3069)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil.lambda$0(JFaceUtil.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:794)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1110)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4173)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3986)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3585)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1160)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1049)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
```

Please let me know if I need to change any configuration

Comment: It looks like the code is doing something that Java 17 no longer allows - various attempts to change Java internals are now not allowed. You will need to use newer versions of the code that support Java 17.

Comment: you mean to say I need to change the code as per java 17 standards? @greg-449

Comment: The code having the problem is part of Eclipse JDT - so you need a newer version of Eclipse/STS